# Same Remote Validation for 2 different properties in a model

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, remote-validation

I have 2 properties contractor1 and contractor2 in a model, how can I use a single remote validation for both of them

```
[Display(Name ="Contractor 1:")]
[Remote("ValidateContractor", "Contracts")]
public string Cntrctr1 {get; set;}

[Display(Name = "Contractor 2:")]
[Remote("ValidateContractor", "Contracts")]`enter code here`
public string Cntrctr2 {get; set;}
```

Remote Validation function in the Controller

```
public JsonResult ValidateContractor1(string Cntrctr)
{
    var valid = Validations.ValidateContractor(Cntrctr);
    if (!valid)
    {return Json("Enter correct contractor", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);}
    else{return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);}
}
public static bool ValidateContractor(string CntrctrNM)
{
    bool valid;
    using (var entities = new CAATS_Entities())
    {
        var result = (from t in entities.PS_VENDOR_V
                      where (t.VNDR_1_NM).Equals(CntrctrNM) 
                      select t).FirstOrDefault();
        if (result != null)
        {
            valid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            valid = false;
        }
    }
    return valid;

}
```

This doesn't work. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: it returns "Enter Correct Contractor", it doesn't pass the validation although u enter the right value into the fields

Comment: Are you sure that var result = (from ...); returns something?

Comment: property value null is passed when ValidateContractor1 is called for remote validation,

Comment: you have already accepted the answer, still a little more info. I was trying for the same as I had to use the same method from different models. But the name of model property and name of parameter should be same, which is not in your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When remote validation is called, the querystring key is the name of the field, e.g. in your case `/Contracts/ValidateContractor1?Cntrctr1=foo`. You need a more dynamic solution.

One way you can do this is to not have any parameters in `ValidateContractor1` and just grab the first query string value instead. This isn't tested but should work for you:

```
public JsonResult ValidateContractor1()
{
   // gets the name of the property being validated, e.g. "Cntrctr1"
   string fieldName = Request.QueryString.Keys[0];

   // gets the value to validate
   string Cntrctr = Request.QueryString[fieldName];

   // carry on as before
   var valid = Validations.ValidateContractor(Cntrctr);
   if (!valid)
   {return Json("Enter correct contractor", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);}
   else{return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);}
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much, been looking for this solution for a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto Rhumborls answer if you find his method not to work it might be because you're using forms; if this is the case you need to use the Form attribute instead of the QueryString as so.

```
public JsonResult ValidateContractor()
{
    // gets the name of the property being validated, e.g. "Cntrctr1"
    string fieldName = Request.Form.Keys[0];

    // gets the value to validate
    string Cntrctr = Request.Form[fieldName];

    // carry on as before
    var valid = Validations.ValidateContractor(Cntrctr);
    if (!valid)
    {return Json("Enter correct contractor", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);}
    else{return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);}
}
```